# What are files that end in ~ on OSX? (e.g. test.txt~)

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I'm simply wondering what files that end with ~ are used for. Also, while I'm here, what types of files are generally "hidden", as well, which on OSX are .-prefixed. Are hidden files and ~-suffixed files used for the same thing on Ubuntu as on OSX?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The files ending with tilda ~ are usually temporary files, probably leaved by some editor. So it depends of the software

The files, start with dot . are hidden files by UNIX (and linux) design.

The purpose of temporary files is to give you backup in case of crash of your editor which can put edited file in unpredictable condition. If you are sure about the condition of edited file you can safe remote temporary files.

The purpose of hidden files is (obvious) to hide some files from "first/fast" look of files in particular directory. Usually they keep some configurations. The same (dot as first symbol in name) is true about directories. Usually it's wise do not touching hidden files except you know what exactly you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank you. :) What is the purpose of hidden and temporary files? What could deleting these types of files potentially do? I imagine any file can be made hidden, so that last question is probably geared towards temporary files only.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: deleting a ._DSStore file would make the Finder 'forget' the remembered position of that folder [safe]. Deleting ./private would prevent your machine from starting up [very nasty] … which is why they're not meant to be played with, without some serious research.